# Better method to Split Cell values in multiple Rows and Concatenate these values in the next Column with formatting intact using Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Here is the view of my excel sheet:
[image]

**Document Overview:**

It has multiple columns which may vary as per the requirement.Document ID's and Document Versions are always available in each sheet, however the Name of the Column (Ex; Doc ID or ID / Doc Version or Doc #) and Columns (Ex; Column G & H / Column J & K) may vary.

In this case, Document ID - Column C and Document version - Column D may contain multiple values in each cell.

Document Id always has 9 digits (filled with trailing zeros if the Id does not have enough digits). Ex; **000**987094, 123456100 , 234567899, **0**23456789 etc.

Document Version always has the fixed format of "0.0" or "00.0", Ex; 1.0, 23.0, 2.1 etc.

**Description of what I have done so far:**

I use VBA Macro to split the Cells containing multiple values (ID and related Versions, highlighted in the uploaded image) into rows below them.  After that I Concatenate the Split Values into next column by inserting a new column manually and then using another Macro to Concatenate.

Here is the Output after I run the Macro:

[image]

**Macros:**

```
    Sub SplitCellValuesIntoRows()

        Dim rng_all_data As Range
        'Set rng_all_data = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Range of cells:", Type:=8)
        Set rng_all_data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Dim int_row As Integer
        int_row = 0

        On Error Resume Next

        Dim sht_out As Worksheet
        Set sht_out = Worksheets.Add

        Dim rng_row As Range
        For Each rng_row In rng_all_data.Rows

            Dim int_col As Integer
            int_col = 0

            Dim int_max_splits As Integer
            int_max_splits = 0

            Dim rng_col As Range
            For Each rng_col In rng_row.Columns

                Dim col_parts As Variant
                col_parts = Split(rng_col, vbLf)

                If UBound(col_parts) > int_max_splits Then
                    int_max_splits = UBound(col_parts)
                End If

                 sht_out.Range("A1").Offset(int_row, int_col).Resize(UBound(col_parts) + 1) = Application.Transpose(col_parts)

                int_col = int_col + 1
            Next

            int_row = int_row + int_max_splits + 1
        Next

    End Sub



Sub Join_em()

    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Range("E" & i).Formula = (Range("C" & i).Value & " " & Range("D" & i).Value)
    Next i

End Sub
```

In the macro Join_em(), I fill the values manually after using the first Macro SplitCellValuesIntoRows(), based on the output columns of Document ID and Document Version to get the Concatenated values.

```
Range("E" & i).Formula = (Range("C" & i).Value & " " & Range("D" & i).Value)
```

**C, D** and **E** in this case.

**What I want to achieve:**

I am trying to achieve something like this as the output:

[image]

1. Split the Cells with multiple values by adding rows in the **same sheet** and keep the destination cell **formatting intact**.
2. **Add a new Column** E (in this case) and Concatenate the values from Document ID and Document Version **with the leading and trailing zeroes** intact.
3. Since the format for Document ID (9 digits with/without trailing zeroes) and Document versions ("0.0" or "00.0") are always fixed, but the Name and Column # are not fixed, Is it possible to use regex and combine the respective cells into newly inserted column beside them automatically after splitting multiple cell values into individual rows. (It would be awesome to get to know how to make it work,I have tried it without success. I don't know the logic to make it work)

Here is the link for downloading the dummy Excel Sheet, in case it is needed for clarity.

[DummyBook.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14CQfDEv9uqxT21iMd-JbEhNLpvr9YP4o/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finding your columns**

`Regex` solutions are extremely useful when you are looking for complex string combinations, but in VBA they can be a little slow. Given the simplicity of your match patterns, it'd probably easier and faster to use more 'primitive' string comparisons. Say, for example, your Document Id's are between 10000 and 1000000000, you could simply try to convert your string to a `Long` and see if the value is between those numbers. A similar approach could be used comparing each side of a decimal for your Document Version comparison.

With any string comparison, `Regex` or otherwise, you need to guard against false matches. The value of cell "A3", for example, matches the pattern of a Document Version. So you need to put in place some safeguards to prevent your code selecting the wrong column; only you will know what those could reliably be, but it might be something as simple as saying a Document Version can only occur in Column "C" or after.

**Concatenating the values**

In your spreadsheet, all cells are formatted as `Text`. This means that even numbers will be interpreted as strings - hence the little green triangle warning you of this in your ID and Version cells. Had they been numbers, then you'd have needed to apply a number format to those cells (eg `#0.#` for the Version). For your spreadsheet, concatenation is no more complicated than joining the two strings as in `str = str1 & " " & str2`.

In your second image, it looks as though you have a `General` cell format (or perhaps some kind of number format) so those values are interpreted as numbers. These would need to be formatted before concatenation, using the `NumberFormat()` function.

**Splitting the rows**

Splitting cells into rows, although syntactically easy, can be fiddly when you're trying to keep track of which row you're investigating. The way that I do it is to store the pertinent rows in a `Collection` and I keep referencing those collection objects as I need them. The advantage of this is that the `Range` reference in the `Collection` updates itself whenever rows are added.

All in all, then, your code is relatively straightforward and an example of how it could work is given below. You'll note that I haven't bothered formatting the new rows and columns - that's fairly trivial and is something you could do yourself to suit your own needs. This code should be put in a Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ID_IDX As Long = 0
Private Const VER_IDX As Long = 1
Private Const RNG_IDX As Long = 2

Private Sub RunMe()
    Dim data As Variant, cols As Variant, items As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim ids() As String, vers() As String
    Dim addItems As Collection, concatItems As Collection
    Dim dataRng As Range, rng As Range
    Dim writeID() As Variant, writeVer() As Variant, writeConcat() As Variant
    Dim dataStartRow As Long

    'Define the range we're interested in and read into an array.
    With Sheet1 'adjust for your worksheet object
        Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
                      .Resize(, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
       End With
    data = dataRng.Value2
    dataStartRow = 2

    'Find the two target columns
    cols = AcquireIdAndVerCol(data, 3, 8)
    If IsEmpty(cols) Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find Id and Ver columns."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With dataRng
        'Add a column next to the version number column.
        .Columns(cols(VER_IDX)).Offset(, 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        'Add a column to our range.
        'This is to cover the case that the rightmost column is the version number column.
        Set dataRng = .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
    End With

    'Find the rows that need to be split and concatenate the target strings.
    Set addItems = New Collection
    Set concatItems = New Collection
    For r = dataStartRow To UBound(data, 1)

        ids = Split(data(r, cols(ID_IDX)), vbLf)
        vers = Split(data(r, cols(VER_IDX)), vbLf)
        n = IIf(UBound(ids) >= UBound(vers), UBound(ids), UBound(vers))

        If n = 0 Then 'it's just one line of text.

            'Add concatenated text to list.
            concatItems.Add data(r, cols(ID_IDX)) & " " & data(r, cols(VER_IDX))

        ElseIf n > 0 Then 'it's multiple lines of text.

            'Transpose the id array.
            ReDim writeID(1 To UBound(ids) + 1, 1 To 1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(ids)
                writeID(i + 1, 1) = ids(i)
            Next
            'Transpose the version array.
            ReDim writeVer(1 To UBound(vers) + 1, 1 To 1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(ids)
                writeVer(i + 1, 1) = vers(i)
            Next

            'Add concatenated text to list.
            For i = 0 To n
                concatItems.Add (IIf(UBound(ids) <= n And UBound(vers) <= n, ids(i) & " " & vers(i), Empty))
            Next

            'Add the range to be split to the collection.
            addItems.Add Array(writeID, writeVer, dataRng.Rows(r + 1).Resize(n))

        Else 'it's an empty cell

            'Add empty item to concatenated list in order to keep alignment.
            concatItems.Add Empty

        End If

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Split the ranges in the list.
    If addItems.Count > 0 Then
        For Each items In addItems
            'Add the rows.
            With items(RNG_IDX)
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                Set rng = .Offset(-.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
                'Note: format your rng Range obect as desired here.
            End With
            'Write the id and version values.
            rng.Columns(cols(ID_IDX)).Value = items(ID_IDX)
            rng.Columns(cols(VER_IDX)).Value = items(VER_IDX)
        Next
    End If

    'Write the concatenated values.
    If concatItems.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim writeConcat(1 To concatItems.Count + dataStartRow - 1, 1 To 1)
        'Header to array.
        writeConcat(1, 1) = "Concat values"
        'Values from the collection to array.
        i = dataStartRow
        For Each items In concatItems
            writeConcat(i, 1) = items
            i = i + 1
        Next
        'Output array to range.
        With dataRng.Columns(cols(VER_IDX) + 1)
            .Value = writeConcat
            .AutoFit
        End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function AcquireIdAndVerCol(data As Variant, minCol As Long, maxCol As Long) As Variant
    Dim result(1) As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    Dim items() As String

    'Check we're not operating outside bounds of data array.
    If minCol < LBound(data, 2) Then minCol = LBound(data, 2)
    If minCol > UBound(data, 2) Then minCol = UBound(data, 2)
    If maxCol < LBound(data, 2) Then maxCol = LBound(data, 2)
    If maxCol > UBound(data, 2) Then maxCol = UBound(data, 2)

    'Loop through data to find the two columns.
    'Once found, leave the function.
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        For c = minCol To maxCol
            items = Split(data(r, c), vbLf)
            For i = 0 To UBound(items)
                If result(ID_IDX) = 0 Then
                    If IsDocId(items(i)) Then
                        result(ID_IDX) = c
                        If result(VER_IDX) = 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            AcquireIdAndVerCol = result
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                If result(VER_IDX) = 0 Then
                    If IsDocVer(items(i)) Then
                        result(VER_IDX) = c
                        If result(ID_IDX) = 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            AcquireIdAndVerCol = result
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Function
Private Function IsDocId(val As String) As Boolean
    Dim n As Long

    n = TryClng(val)
    IsDocId = (n > 9999 And n <= 999999999)
End Function

Private Function IsDocVer(val As String) As Boolean
    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    Dim items() As String

    items = Split(val, ".")
    If UBound(items) <> 1 Then Exit Function

    n = TryClng(items(0))
    m = TryClng(items(1))

    IsDocVer = (n > 0 And n <= 99) And (m >= 0 And m <= 9)
End Function

'-------------------------------------------------------------------
'Converts a variant to a Long or returns a fail value as a Long
'if the conversion failed.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function TryClng(expr As Variant, Optional fail As Long = -1) As Long
    Dim n As Long

    n = fail
    On Error Resume Next
    n = CLng(expr)
    On Error GoTo 0

    TryClng = n
End Function
```

Comment: I can't Thank you enough. It works very well and your explanation is great. I learned a LOT. The way you have added a validation for finding Id's and Version is simply awesome. And at last, I would like to seek your counsel for cases like such:

Comment: [Case1](https://imgur.com/a/urJQwWM) where there is one version number only, bound to 4 or more Id's. Since we are using an array to output the concat values, It gets disoriented like [this](https://imgur.com/a/yFvFTjA) (in Concat values column) if the number of items in ID column and number of items in VERSION column doesn't match. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Be happy to help again - the way this site works is you simply post new questions even if it relates to an old question. Just show what code you already have, what new problem you are trying to solve, and what you've already done to try and fix the problem. I'll keep any eye of for the new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the range or sheet (not "Entire Workbook") as "Web Page (*.htm;*.html)", and open the resulting .htm file in Excel. After that you can unmerge all cells and add borders as needed :

[image]