# Manipulating Collections and Arrays in Excel VBA to accommodate missing values and error handling

Tags: vba, excel

I did not know how to explain the question so I will attach images for explaining my situation. Here is the view of my Excel Sheet:

My Excel Sheet

[image]

The highlighted cells contain multiple values called **ID's** and are associated with respective **Versions** in the columns beside them. I use the following macro [(details with great explanation here)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52456559/6765626) to split these values into multiple rows in the same sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ID_IDX As Long = 0
Private Const VER_IDX As Long = 1
Private Const RNG_IDX As Long = 2

Private Sub RunMe()
    Dim data As Variant, cols As Variant, items As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim ids() As String, vers() As String
    Dim addItems As Collection, concatItems As Collection
    Dim dataRng As Range, rng As Range
    Dim writeID() As Variant, writeVer() As Variant, writeConcat() As Variant
    Dim dataStartRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    'Define the range we're interested in and read into an array.
    With Sheet1 'adjust for your worksheet object
        Set dataRng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Range of cells:", Type:=8)
       End With
    data = dataRng.Value2
    dataStartRow = 2

    'Find the two target columns
    cols = AcquireIdAndVerCol(data, 3, 8)
    If IsEmpty(cols) Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find Id and Ver columns."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With dataRng
        'Add a column next to the version number column.
        .Columns(cols(VER_IDX)).Offset(, 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        'Add a column to our range.
        'This is to cover the case that the rightmost column is the version number column.
        Set dataRng = .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
    End With

    'Find the rows that need to be split and concatenate the target strings.
    Set addItems = New Collection
    Set concatItems = New Collection
    For r = dataStartRow To UBound(data, 1)

        ids = Split(data(r, cols(ID_IDX)), vbLf)
        vers = Split(data(r, cols(VER_IDX)), vbLf)
        n = IIf(UBound(ids) >= UBound(vers), UBound(ids), UBound(vers))

        If n = 0 Then 'it's just one line of text.

            'Add concatenated text to list.
            concatItems.Add data(r, cols(ID_IDX)) & " " & data(r, cols(VER_IDX))

        ElseIf n > 0 Then 'it's multiple lines of text.

            'Transpose the id array.
            ReDim writeID(1 To UBound(ids) + 1, 1 To 1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(ids)
                writeID(i + 1, 1) = ids(i)
            Next
            'Transpose the version array.
            ReDim writeVer(1 To UBound(vers) + 1, 1 To 1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(ids)
                writeVer(i + 1, 1) = vers(i)
            Next

            'Add concatenated text to list.
            For i = 0 To n
                concatItems.Add (IIf(UBound(ids) <= n And UBound(vers) <= n, ids(i) & " " & vers(i), Empty))
            Next

            'Add the range to be split to the collection.
            addItems.Add Array(writeID, writeVer, dataRng.Rows(r + 1).Resize(n))

        Else 'it's an empty cell

            'Add empty item to concatenated list in order to keep alignment.
            concatItems.Add Empty

        End If

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Split the ranges in the list.
    If addItems.Count > 0 Then
        For Each items In addItems
            'Add the rows.
            With items(RNG_IDX)
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                Set rng = .Offset(-.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
                'Note: format your rng Range obect as desired here.
            End With
            'Write the id and version values.
            rng.Columns(cols(ID_IDX)).Value = items(ID_IDX)
            rng.Columns(cols(VER_IDX)).Value = items(VER_IDX)
        Next
    End If

    'Write the concatenated values.
    If concatItems.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim writeConcat(1 To concatItems.Count + dataStartRow - 1, 1 To 1)
        'Header to array.
        writeConcat(1, 1) = "Concat values"
        'Values from the collection to array.
        i = dataStartRow
        For Each items In concatItems
            writeConcat(i, 1) = items
            i = i + 1
        Next
        'Output array to range.
        With dataRng.Columns(cols(VER_IDX) + 1)
            .Value = writeConcat
            .AutoFit
        End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function AcquireIdAndVerCol(data As Variant, minCol As Long, maxCol As Long) As Variant
    Dim result(1) As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    Dim items() As String

    'Check we're not operating outside bounds of data array.
    If minCol < LBound(data, 2) Then minCol = LBound(data, 2)
    If minCol > UBound(data, 2) Then minCol = UBound(data, 2)
    If maxCol < LBound(data, 2) Then maxCol = LBound(data, 2)
    If maxCol > UBound(data, 2) Then maxCol = UBound(data, 2)

    'Loop through data to find the two columns.
    'Once found, leave the function.
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        For c = minCol To maxCol
            items = Split(data(r, c), vbLf)
            For i = 0 To UBound(items)
                If result(ID_IDX) = 0 Then
                    If IsDocId(items(i)) Then
                        result(ID_IDX) = c
                        If result(VER_IDX) = 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            AcquireIdAndVerCol = result
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                If result(VER_IDX) = 0 Then
                    If IsDocVer(items(i)) Then
                        result(VER_IDX) = c
                        If result(ID_IDX) = 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            AcquireIdAndVerCol = result
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Function
Private Function IsDocId(val As String) As Boolean
    Dim n As Long

    n = TryClng(val)
    IsDocId = (n > 9999 And n <= 999999999)
End Function

Private Function IsDocVer(val As String) As Boolean
    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    Dim items() As String

    items = Split(val, ".")
    If UBound(items) <> 1 Then Exit Function

    n = TryClng(items(0))
    m = TryClng(items(1))

    IsDocVer = (n > 0 And n <= 99) And (m >= 0 And m <= 9)
End Function

'-------------------------------------------------------------------
'Converts a variant to a Long or returns a fail value as a Long
'if the conversion failed.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function TryClng(expr As Variant, Optional fail As Long = -1) As Long
    Dim n As Long

    n = fail
    On Error Resume Next
    n = CLng(expr)
    On Error GoTo 0

    TryClng = n
End Function
```

It gives the following output with an addition column named, **Concat Values**, which contains combined values of **Id's** and corresponding **Versions**:

Output

[image]

**Problem:**

It works flawlessly if all the ID's have corresponding Versions specified in the sheet separately as I mentioned above. However in cases, where there is only one Version number, and it's bound to 4 or more Id's, i.e. Same Version number is applicable for all the ID's, like such:

[image: Common Version for separate ID's]

The output in the column **Concat Values** gets disoriented because we are using an array to output the Concat Values and the array is not accommodating the missing Versions for corresponding Id's. It looks like this:

Dislocated row values

[image]

I am trying to learn and figure out a way to update the collection and the array with new Concat Values before Outputting it to the column, so that each Concat Value gets placed in their corresponding ID and Version location. I hope that it makes sense. Please let me know for more clarification.

***EDIT:***
I will try and list all the possible Cases and Expected Output, including the worst case scenarios:

Here is the link to [my excel sheet.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14CQfDEv9uqxT21iMd-JbEhNLpvr9YP4o/view?usp=sharing)

### **Usual Scenarios**

1. **Number of Id's  = Number of Versions** (Works perfectly, Concat Values get aligned in corresponding rows in the columns)
   [image: *Number of Id's = Number of Versions:*]
2. **Multiple Id's - Single Version** (In such cases, the Version # applicable to all the ID's is **same** i.e. one Version should be applied to all the ID's.)

**Issue:**
The Macro does the task of splitting the columns into rows, except the part where *Concat values get misaligned.* 
[image: *Multiple Id's - Single Version:*]

### **Worst Case Scenarios**

3. **Multiple Id's - Multiple Versions, but less than total #ID's** (In such cases, Versions should align to the topmost ID's and fill the ID's below with **blanks**)

**Issue:**
The Macro does the task of splitting the columns into rows, except the part where *Concat values get misaligned.*

[image: *Multiple Id's - Multiple Versions - Type 1:*]
Here 4 ID's have been given only 3 Versions, so Top 3 ID's are assigned 3 Versions and the 4th ID has no Version linked to it.

Similarly,

[image: *Multiple Id's - Multiple Versions - Type 2:*]
Here 4 ID's have been given only 2 Versions, so Top 2 ID's are assigned 2 Versions and the 3rd and 4th ID's have no Version linked to them.

4. **Multiple Id's - No Version** (In such cases, columns should split into rows based on #ID's and corresponding Version rows should be filled with **blanks**)

**Issue:**
The Macro does the task of splitting the columns into rows, except the part where *Concat values get misaligned.*

[image: Multiple Id's - No Version]

Comment: Check out this [mrexcel Link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/789648-split-excel-cell-carriage-returns-into-multiple-rows.html)

Comment: So there are only two possible cases: [# of Ids = # of versions], or [>1id + only one version] ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Usually I come across only two cases: {# of IDs = # of Versions} and/or {More than 1 IDs - Only one Version}. But, like you mentioned, Sometimes 4 or more Ids could be associated to 3 or 2 IDs or even completely blank (in cases all the Id's = Placeholders, which don't really have to have Versions).

Comment: Can you post some examples of the different combinations. The 1 version for many Id's is easy to solve, but the multiple versions to multiply Id's is fiddlier. What we need to know is how Id's and version numbers line up within the rows if there are more than one of both.

Comment: @Ambie I have updated my question with examples. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of the solution will depend on the complexity and variety of 'special cases'. Given your scenarios, it seems as if you could just take the last of the given versions and, for any versions missing below that line, just use that last used version.

When I gave my first answer, I anticipated this kind of issue, so changes to the code are trivial.

Firstly add an additional declaration in the `RunMe` Sub:

```
Dim curVer As String
```

and then you just need to adjust the `ElseIf n > 0` case. Replace the code with this:

```
    ElseIf n > 0 Then 'it's multiple lines of text.

        'Resize the output arrays to max ('n')
        ReDim writeID(1 To n + 1, 1 To 1)
        ReDim writeVer(1 To n + 1, 1 To 1)

        'Loop through the arrays to align id and versions.
        For i = 0 To n
            If i <= UBound(ids) Then
                writeID(i + 1, 1) = ids(i)
            End If
            If i <= UBound(vers) Then
                curVer = vers(i)
            End If
            writeVer(i + 1, 1) = curVer
        Next

        'Add concatenated text to list.
        For i = 0 To n
            concatItems.Add writeID(i + 1, 1) & " " & writeVer(i + 1, 1)
        Next

        'Add the range to be split to the collection.
        addItems.Add Array(writeID, writeVer, dataRng.Rows(r + 1).Resize(n))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.This works perfectly now. I modified the code a little and added an Else statement,  to make it suitable for my purpose. 'If i <= UBound(vers) Then curVer = vers(i) Else : curVer = ""  End If'. Thanks again:)

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you'll probably find that you have to fiddle with `If` statements to suit the cases as and when they crop up. If you have any other unusual cases, then all of the additional `If`s could go in the same section of code.

Answer (score 0):

Too much code for me to read but I came up with my solution if I understood you problem correctly.

I guess it could be a good solution if you modify it. With my code it will be easier to produce a new table instead of adding rows I guess. Then you could just add the formatting which should be very easy.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim xArrRange() As Variant
    Dim xNewArrRange() As Variant
    Dim xNewArrRangeResize() As Variant
    Dim xNumberColumns As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim jj As Long

    Set xRange = Range("A2:C5")
    xNumberColumns = 3

    xArrRange = xRange.Value2


    ReDim xNewArrRange(xRange.Rows.Count + 10, xNumberColumns)          ' "xNumberColumns - 1" to have the number of columns
                                                                        ' "xNumberColumns" is one more

    For i = LBound(xArrRange, 1) To UBound(xArrRange, 1)
        Dim xTempArrVer As Variant
        Dim xTempArrID As Variant
        xTempArrVer = Split(xArrRange(i, 3), vbLf)

        If UBound(xTempArrVer) = -1 Then                                ' If there are no version, initialize it with ""
            ReDim xTempArrVer(0)
            xTempArrVer(0) = ""
        End If

        xTempArrID = Split(xArrRange(i, 2), vbLf)

        For j = LBound(xTempArrID, 1) To UBound(xTempArrID, 1)
            If j > UBound(xTempArrVer, 1) Then
                l = UBound(xTempArrVer, 1)
            Else
                l = j
            End If

            xNewArrRange(k, 0) = xArrRange(i, 1)
            xNewArrRange(k, 1) = xTempArrID(j)
            xNewArrRange(k, 2) = xTempArrVer(l)

            If xTempArrVer(l) <> "" Then
                xNewArrRange(k, 3) = xTempArrID(j) & " " & xTempArrVer(l)
            Else
                xNewArrRange(k, 3) = xTempArrID(j)
            End If

            k = k + 1

            If k + 1 > UBound(xNewArrRange, 1) Then
                ReDim Preserve xNewArrRange(UBound(xNewArrRange, 1) + 30, xNumberColumns)
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

    ReDim xNewArrRangeResize(k - 1, xNumberColumns)         ' "xNumberColumns - 1" to have the number of columns
                                                            ' "xNumberColumns" is one more

    For ii = LBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 1) To UBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 1)
        For jj = LBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 2) To UBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 2)
            xNewArrRangeResize(ii, jj) = xNewArrRange(ii, jj)
        Next jj
    Next ii

    Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(UBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 1) + 1, 6 + UBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 2))).Value2 = xNewArrRangeResize

    Debug.Print "Finish"


End Sub
```

This code produces this:

[image]

If your code produces good number of rows for each id etc, the most lazy solution would be just to populate columns of your table with part of my array which is produced at the end.

Edit:
I see there is something missing but that is because I calculated wrongly that Range.

```
Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(UBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 1) + 1, 6 + UBound(xNewArrRangeResize, 2))).Value2 = xNewArrRangeResize
```